# Translation and Use of Stop Codon using list comprehension python

Tags: python, function, translation, biopython

I'm trying to write a function about open reading frame using a dictionary of only the stop codon. The program takes in three letter at a time and if that three letter is one of that stop codon, the program stops and counts the number of letters (the stop codon is NOT counted, nor is anything afterwards). For example, nextStop2('AAAAAAAGTGGGTGCTAGGTTGGC') should return 15. I'm not sure why but the code I wrote below doesn't seem to work. Can anyone give me any advice on how to improve? Thanks!

```
def nextStop2(Seq):
    GeneticCodeStop = {'TAA':'X', 'TAG':'X', 'TGA':'X'}
    seq2 = ''.join(end_of_loop() if GeneticCodeStop[i]=='X' else i for i in Seq)
    return len((seq2)/3)
```

Answer (score 0):

your parens are off you should write len(seq2)/3. but you don't want to divide by 3 (you expect 15 and not 5) so just return len(seq2).

```
def nextStop2(Seq):
    GeneticCodeStop = ['TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA']
    seq2=''
    for i in range(0,len(Seq),3) :
        codon=Seq[i:i+3]
        if codon in GeneticCodeStop:
            break
        seq2+=codon
    return len(seq2)
    
print(nextStop2('AAAAAAAGTGGGTGCTAGGTTGGC') )
>>> 15
```

but i don't know biopython, and i think it should have a function to do this

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I'm trying to do this using list comprehension so I ended up getting this: `def nextStop2(Seq): GeneticCodeStop = {'TAA':'X', 'TAG':'X', 'TGA':'X'} seq2 = ''.join(i if GeneticCodeStop[Seq[i:i+3]]!='X' else end_of_loop() for i in range(0,len(Seq),3) return len(seq2)` (the space is messed up because it is in the comment section). However, python still returns syntax error. Do you know why? Thank you so much!

Comment: you can't put a break in list comprehension, whatever `end_of_loop()` does (if it exists) it won't work. and you can't put if/else before `for` in a list comprehension.